# Banish [locals]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, meta-tags

The [locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locals) meta-tag has 66 questions and a few meanings:

- [Python's `locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) function (returns  "a dictionary representing the current local symbol table")
- [Locals window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238778(v=vs.60).aspx) ("displays the values and types of all variables that are within the scope of the currently executing procedure")
- Local variables
- [Ruby On Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) ("You can also pass in arbitrary local variables to any partial you are rendering with the `locals`")
- Typo: [locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locale) (retagged 2 questions)
- `localStorage` from JavaScript (retagged 1 question)

Since SO has the [local-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-variables) tag (464 questions) and in most cases people mean "local variables" when they tag their questions with [locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locals), it would be fine to **synonymize them**.

Other options:

1. Change [locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locals) to [local-variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/local-variables) everywhere (burninate it to avoid further confusion).
2. Divide [locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locals) into [python-locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-locals), [visual-studio-locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-locals) etc. (probably not the best idea, since then these tags will contain ~20 questions each)

Opinions?

***Update:*** [I proposed the synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-variables/synonyms).

Answer (score 6):

To synonymize `Locals` with `Local variables` seems most sensible to me.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea since not all "locals" usage are about local variables, as the Python example demonstrate and dominates in the share.

Comment: @Braiam: The question has, besides typos, only identified one case that isn't about local variables (javascript local storage)

Comment: @BenVoigt you are missing the point. "locals" doesn't mean "local variables" on **all programming contexts**. It can mean the use of a function to get local variables (aka X to obtain Y), something that wants to be called "locals" but it's actually partials in Ruby (aka Z to set Y), and a window to see those "locals variables" in VS (aka P to see Y), where X, Z and P are three different things with similar naming yet different purposes and functionality which only point in common is that they have something to do with "local variables". Y obviously is the "locals variables".

Comment: @Braiam: No, I'm not missing the point.  There are multiple things you can do with local variables (language rules concerning local variables, or inspect them at runtime using a debugger or reflection API), but they are all still about the same topic: local variables.  Disambiguation is needed when the term means different things at different times, not when there are multiple questions about the same thing.  All of these are fundamentally about the same thing.

Comment: @BenVoigt if you are tasked with writing a tag excerpt for this tag, what would be the body of it? Remember you have to capture the complete usage, not just a part of it.

Comment: @Braiam: Says who?  If that were true, some tag wikis would have to be hundreds of pages long.  Saying that the variables are associated to a particular function, and mentioning scope, lifetime, and recursion should be adequate.  What you don't have to do is create overspecified tags for general concepts.  For example, the "python-locals" tag suggested in the question should be a combination of [tag:local-variables] and [tag:reflection].  Many languages besides python allow enumeration of the local symbol table (example: Matlab).

Comment: And rather than "visual-studio-locals-window", use [tag:local-variables] together with [tag:debugger].  The same feature is available in Eclipse, Code Composer Studio, and pretty much every IDE in existence.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I disagree for the simple reason that I think [tag:local-variables] is insufficiently specific to be a good tag. I'd probably tag with [tag:reflection] and the language tag, I think.